# How to determine the source view controller of a transition

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, segue, navigationcontroller

I've created three different view controllers in Xcode's storyboard and connected them via a Navigation controller and appropriate segues.

Is there a method which can be invoked in the destination view controller to determine from which view controller the segue was performed?

So I'm looking for the opposite of the "prepareSegue" method. Maybe there is a method like "sourceViewController" or similar....

Thanks you so far!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably not get direct name of that class but you can assume and compare the class names with the property or objects of that view controller you just created.

For Eg. going from A or C to B you can compare the properties/objects of A/C in B with method **isMemberOfClass/isKindOfclass**. 
 Hope this works :)